# Socket.IO throwing Type Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, bcrypt

I have a simple NodeJS server that uses bcrypt, mysql and socket.IO, that works as a gateway for a mysql database and a chat server. This server connects to the client using Socket.IO client, and sends requests to the server using Socket.IO events. However, the registration event throws a `Type Error : undefined is not a function`. I have checked all the functions and they exist, so i don't know what is happening. Here is my code to handle the registration event :

```
socket.on('registration request', function(msg,err) {
        var split = msg.toString().split(":§:");
        var userName = split[0];
        var password = split[1];
        var email = split[2];

        console.log("Registration request : " + userName + " <===> " + email); //<====== Prints this to the console then crashes and returns the message below
        if(err){
            console.log("Socket Error !!\n" + err);
        }
        if (pattern.test(userName) && emailRegex.test(email)) {
            console.log("Data is valid. Coding password");
            password = bcrypt.hashSync(password.toString(), 2);
            console.log("Querying DB");
            DBConnection.query(
                    "INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_password,user_email) VALUES (\""
                            + userName + "\" , \"" + password + "\" , \""
                            + email + "\");", function(error, rows) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("Something went wrong in registering " + userName);
                            sIO.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('registration response', "<ERROR>");
                        } else if (rows.length > 1) {
                            console.log("Registration of " + userName + " succeded");
                            sIO.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('registration response', "<SUCCESS>");
                        } else {
                            console.log("Registration of " + userName + "denied")
                            sIO.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('registration response', "<DENIED>");
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            socket.emit('registration response', "<DENIED>");
        }
    });
```

And here is the error message :

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/ChatServer/index.js:109:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:330:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:290:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.onPacket (/root/ChatServer/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:99:14)
```

I can't find my error. Your help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about `socket.io`. So here it goes...

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
```

I think this is a warning (meaning that it didn't break anything, just letting you know about possible bad coding practice), that you didn't add `socket.on('error', function (err) { console.error(err.stack); // TODO, cleanup })`. Often one would close and the socket and start a new one, or just end the whole process when something like this happens. Maybe it is better just to log and do nothing. Check with `socket` documentation.

Your actual error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/ChatServer/index.js:109:15)
```

I am guessing that you are the author of `index.js`. **I need to know what is on line 109.** Please post this as a comment and I can help further. Also it might help if you tell me if any of your `console.log` lines worked, and what their output was.

Comment: Line 109 : `if (!pattern.test(userName) && emailRegex.test(email)) {`
And the console logs work fine. They only notify of a user arrival

Comment: Looks like the problem is `pattern` and/or `emailRegex` are not actually regular expressions. Therefore `pattern.test` and/or `emailRegex.test` is `undefined`.

Comment: You need to look at and/or share the code that initializes these two. (something like `pattern=`) It may help if you add a `console.log(pattern, emailRegex)` to see what they are. (Since they are not regular expressions like you expected them to be.)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long.
You're right! I forgot to initialize emailRegex as a Regular Expression.